# Flutter check GPS status continuously

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, provider

I'm working on an application that requires the user location continuously. If the user disables GPS, I want to show an error screen. How do I do it using a provider maybe?

Comment: Did you find any better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) plugin. You can do the task which requires location permission inside if block and shows the error message if the permission is revoked.

```dart
if (await Permission.locationWhenInUse.serviceStatus.isEnabled) {
  // Use location.
} else {
  // show error
}
```

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58024956/4788260) answer which can help you to listen to the permission change.

Comment: This gives me the answer. But so does the locator and geolocator. I want to have a stream of these and when it changes, I want to display the error message. Like we have Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Please mark and upvote the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: Yes. Will do. I just haven't tried it yet. I'll upvote both of them.