# How to listen if location service is enabled while the app is running in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter app which needs location services. Some features can be used without location services are enabled. But I want to listen the location services whether it is enable or disable, according to that I will run some processes. For example I will open location while i am using the app, and I need some function that will be triggered after i enable location.

I am using Geolocator.
Thanks.

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55442995/flutter-how-do-i-listen-to-permissions-real-time

Comment: check Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled(); and Geolocator.checkPermission(); it you use https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator

Comment: Can you please share the Code Snippet of what you have implemented?

Answer (score 6):

By using flutter geolocator, your code will throw an `LocationServiceDisabledException` when location service is disabled. Check the documentation [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/geolocator_platform_interface/latest/geolocator_platform_interface/LocationServiceDisabledException-class.html).

Otherwise you can listen for service status changes by calling the `getServiceStatusStream`. This will return a `Stream<ServiceStatus>` which can be listened to, to receive location service status updates.

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

StreamSubscription<ServiceStatus> serviceStatusStream = Geolocator.getServiceStatusStream().listen(
    (ServiceStatus status) {
        print(status);
    });
```

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Permission handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) plugin to check whether the user have granted a certain permission before using it, for your case you can check the location permission status by -

```
// import the plugin

if (Permission.location.status) { // Returns true if granted
    // use location feature 
} else {
    Permission.location.request(); // ask for the permission
}
```

You can use all the request as follows by the permission_handler plugin, check the pub dev for its documentation.

Hope it helps.