# Flutter check location permission handler

Tags: flutter, dart, permissions

I need to give a warning as soon as the user turns off the location permission.

Is it possible to catch the moment when he turns off the permission?

Comment: Hello, Try this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55442995/flutter-how-do-i-listen-to-permissions-real-time

Comment: You can use the location pacakge https://pub.dev/packages/location