# How to check location permission status with permission_handler in Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, user-permissions, pub.dev

I'm building a Flutter app that requires location permission to work properly. I'm using the permission_handler package to handle permissions, but I'm having trouble checking the current status of the location permission. Specifically, I want to give the user a warning as soon as they turn off the location permission. How can I check the current status of the location permission using permission_handler in Flutter?
I've tried using the checkPermissionStatus method from the permission_handler package, but I'm not sure how to handle the different permission statuses (granted, denied, etc.) and how to give the user a warning when the permission is turned off.
Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void checkLocationPermission() async {
  var status = await Permission.location.status;
  if (status.isDenied) {
    // Show warning to user
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I've tried using the checkPermissionStatus method from the permission_handler package, but I'm not sure how to handle the different permission statuses (granted, denied, etc.) and how to give the user a warning when the permission is turned off.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have shown?  If permission is `denied` then show your warning. If it is `granted` then don't show the warning.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58024956/13625293

Comment: Or this, a simpler solution with `flutter_hooks` https://stackoverflow.com/a/74660451/13625293